# Unique array comprehension

Tags: javascript, arrays, coffeescript

I have the following array in CoffeeScript:

```
electric_mayhem = [ { name: "Doctor Teeth", instrument: "piano" },
                { name: "Janice", instrument: "piano" },
                { name: "Sgt. Floyd Pepper", instrument: "bass" },
                { name: "Zoot", instrument: "sax" },
                { name: "Lips", instrument: "bass" },
                { name: "Animal", instrument: "drums" } ]
```

My goal is to get all instrument names from this array.

Expected result: `['piano', 'bass', 'sax', 'drums']`

My first solution based on [this](http://coffeescriptcookbook.com/chapters/arrays/removing-duplicate-elements-from-arrays):

```
names = (muppet.instrument for muppet in electric_mayhem)
output = {}
output[name] = name for name in names
names = (value for key, value of output)
```

This is rather long. I looket at the transpiled javascript, and saw the first line is translated to:

```
names = (function() {
  var _i, _len, _results;
  _results = [];
  for (_i = 0, _len = electric_mayhem.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
    muppet = electric_mayhem[_i];
    _results.push(muppet.instrument);
  }
  return _results;
})();
```

So I made up a super-hacky solution that uses the `_results` variable introduced during transpilation:

```
names = (muppet.instrument for muppet in electric_mayhem \
  when muppet.instrument not in _results)
```

It works, but I don't like it relies on not documented variable name so it may break with future releases of CoffeeScript.

Is there any one-liner to achieve "unique comprehension" in a non-hacky way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one-liner will probably do the trick:

```
names = (key for key of (new -> @[o.instrument] = '' for o in electric_mayhem; @))
//                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
//                                 "object comprehension"
```

As yourself, I (ab)used an associative array to use its keys as the set of unique values.

But, the real *trick* here is the use of an "object comprehension" to build that array. Or at least, its closest equivalent form currently available on CoffeeScript:

```
    (new -> @[o.instrument] = '' for o in electric_mayhem; @)
//   ^^^  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  ^  
//  create                 with                            |
//  a new                  that                            |
//  empty                anonymous                         |
//  object               constructor                       |
//                                           don't forget -/
//                                           to return the
//                                        newly created object
```

Comment: cool! definitely a novel way to return unique values by re-assigning the key in the object. Nice pure CoffeeScript solution.