# Destructuring regex groups into object instead of array

Tags: javascript, regex, coffeescript

I have this regex `^\w+-(\w+)-(\w+)-(\w+)` that I de-structure in CoffeeScript like this:

```
result = {}
[_, result.serialNumber, result.caseId, result.sequenceNumber] = /\w+-(\w+)-(\w+)-(\w+)/.exec(file.name)
```

But I would like to have a more general way of not knowing the object keys beforehand but embed them in the returned regex groups like this pseudo-code

```
/\w+-(serialNumber:\w+)-(caseId:\w+)-(sequenceNumber:\w+)/.exec(file.name)
```

And have a little function that creates the object from that information.

Possible?

Comment: You can build dynamic regex with the `RegExp` constructor, if that's what you're asking..

Comment: How would that help in my case?

Comment: JS stock regexes don't support named groups. [xregexp](http://xregexp.com/) does.

Comment: @georg that lib looks nice, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One way I can think of staying within the pure JS world might be something like this, by splatting the match objects into a pre-defined funciton:

```
str = "ABC-def-hij-klm"

yieldObject = (matchData, serialNumber="", caseId="", sequenceNumber="") ->
  serialNumber: serialNumber
  caseId: caseId
  sequenceNumber: sequenceNumber

yieldObject(str.match(/\w+-(\w+)-(\w+)-(\w+)/)...)
```

you could also use a bit of an object factory to do something similar to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25260425/unique-array-comprehension)
and use object comprehension and a bit of partial application to make the process more applicable elsewhere:

```
str = "ABC-def-hij-klm"

objectBuilder = (keys...)->
  (matchData, matches...)->
    (new -> @[k] = matches[i] for k, i in keys; @)

# yieldObject is a function ready to accept the regex
yieldObject = objectBuilder('serialNumber', 'caseId', 'sequenceNumber')

# splatting the regex makes it into an array of values
yieldObject(str.match(/\w+-(\w+)-(\w+)-(\w+)/)...) #=> Object {serialNumber: "def", caseId: "hij", sequenceNumber: "klm"}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would go for as far as extending `RegExp` prototype with a *builder* function:

```
RegExp::builder = (map...) ->
    re = this
    (str) -> new -> m = str.match(re)[1..]; @[field] = m.shift() for field in map; @

# Create a builder function that maps re groups to members
builder = /\w+-(\w+)-(\w+)-(\w+)/.builder("serialNumber", "caseId", "sequenceNumber")

# build as much objects as you want with the same builder:
obj = builder "ABC-def-hij-klm" 
console.log obj

obj = builder "ABC-ddd-hhh-kkk" 
console.log obj
```

Producing:

```
{ serialNumber: 'def', caseId: 'hij', sequenceNumber: 'klm' }
{ serialNumber: 'ddd', caseId: 'hhh', sequenceNumber: 'kkk' }
```

Comment: fun idea @Sylvan! like the fluid interface.